# Mysql select value of the key from single field of table having multiple key-value pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table like :

services:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id | name      | service_id | description |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | CHAT      |      1     |             |
| 2  | SMS       |      1     |             |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

service_features:

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
| id | service_id | name       | description |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
|10  |          1 | Audio      |             |
|20  |          1 | Video      |             |
|30  |          2 | BULKSMS    |             |
+----+------------+------------+-------------+
```

client_services:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | client_id | service_id |service_features_id               |service_values                               |
+----+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|100 |      1000 |          1 |features:{10:enable, 20:disable}  |values:{data_transfer:102400, quota:204800}  |
|200 |      1001 |          2 |features:{30:enable}              |values:{total_sms:100000, users:800}         |
|300 |      1001 |          1 |features:{10:disable, 20:enable}  |values:{quota:204800}                        |
+----+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

now I want the service value of any key i.e data_transfer or quota for client_id 1000 only from mysql select query. **Answer should be 102400 or 204800 respectively**

Is there any better way to formalize the tables or storing the information. Please suggest.

Comment: How do the feature values relate to the service_features?  For example how do you know what data_transfer and quota goes with?  You definitely want to normalize the data, but we need to know a little more about how the relationships work.

Comment: @Tom : Edited the column name to service_values and we are mapping client with service_id

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely a better way.  Your schema needs two more tables, `client_services_features` and a `client_services_values`, instead of `client_services`.  `client_services_features` has columns such as:

- id
- client_id
- services_id
- service_feature_id
- isEnabled

And `client_services_values` has columns such as:

- id
- client_id
- services_id
- value_name
- value_value

Whenever you find a table structure that is keeping lists of things in a row, you generally want to create a separate table for the list.  When the list contains ids, you always want to create a separete table for the list.

Answer (score 0):

Storing lists of values, json, or xml in a column makes querying for specific data very difficult. It's generally better to break out the data into separate rows.

I would make two other tables

client_services_values:

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------------------+
| id | client_id | service_id |service_type   | service_value   |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------------------+
|1   |      1000 |          1 |data_transfer  | 102400          |
|2   |      1000 |          1 |quota          | 204800          |
|3   |      1001 |          2 |total_sms      | 100000          |
|4   |      1001 |          2 |users          | 800             |
|5   |      1001 |          1 |quota          | 204800          |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------------------+
```

and client_features

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| id | client_id | feature_id | feature_value   |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|1   |      1000 |         10 |enable           |
|2   |      1000 |         20 |disable          |
|3   |      1001 |         30 |enable           |
|4   |      1001 |         10 |disable          |
|5   |      1001 |         20 |enable           |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```